# Two Private Subs in One Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have 2 private subs in one worksheet, the first Private Sub works but the second private sub does not work. Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call AutoFillEtcDataVal 'This script is located in a different module.
End If
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C3"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Call AutoFillMain 'This script is located in a different module.
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` event handler... you have to combine.

Comment: How can I combine those 2?

Comment: Put the `If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C3"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then`, `Call AutoFillMain 'This script is located in a different module.`, `End If` inside the first `Worksheet_Change` handler, after the `End If`.

Comment: Side note: you can change `Range(Target.Address)` to just `Target`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @BigBen! Stay safe....